# Cannot start session without errors (phpmyadmin)?

Tags: command-line, phpmyadmin

I'm getting this:

> Cannot start session without errors,
>   please check errors given in your PHP
>   and/or webserver log file and
>   configure your PHP installation
>   properly.

I followed this tutorial to fix the problem:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/phpmyadmin-cannot-start-session-without-errors/

But I don't actually have a `/var/lib/php/session'` directory.

(I only have a var/lib/php5 directory)

I get this:

```
chown: cannot access `/var/lib/php/session': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

(I didn't touch anything, so I assume an update screwed something).

**EDIT:**

in var/lib/php

there is a file called: **sess_eq4jhtrmumanft46oj7o97phdbtv8bcm**

and it has this:

[image]

(Sorry, I can't paste the code for some reason).

Comment: Pl. tell the content of PHP.ini under session.save_path?

Comment: Can you post output of  'ls -l /var/lib/php5'? If you have directory, session inside, you should treat the command as 'chown -R root:alex /var/lib/php5/session' instead of /var/lib/php/session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the folder `sudo mkdir /var/lib/php/session` and give it a `sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session` privilege (just for testing)

If it start working give it appropriate privilege(using chmod) or change owner (using chown).

Comment: advising 'chmod 777' without explaining what it will do to the security is an overkill, so not recommended.

Comment: @James: Dude he got more reputation than me, I assumed he understands what 'chmod 777' means. In that case you might be saying why I did not explained 'sudo', cuz even working is root is also dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the incorrect settings of php session.save_path. Here is a detailed instruction on how to solve this issue:

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/session.save_path